# Is there a way to filter a report by queues the logged in user is a member of?

Tags: reporting

What I'd like to do is do a dashboard report for users in the service areas that is filtered automatically by the queue(s) they are a member of. Instead of creating a report with a filter for each queue, it would be nice to be able to have the report filter by queues that the user is a member of automatically.

Is there such a way to do this in standard reporting?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there does not seem to be an easy way to report on queues.  You can vote up this idea in the IdeaExchange:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqYaAAK

Also, I found this online which describes using Access after exporting the Group, GroupMember, and User objects from Salesforce - Google BMCRF_QueueMemberReport.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm doing this with APEX code. It requires three queries to get all the stuff I need and it runs in a job that sends an email to recipients.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this ? It's not entirely clear how this is an answer to the question or what to do in apex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is add a formula field:

```
IF( ISBLANK( Owner:Queue.QueueName ) ,"Not Queue", Owner:Queue.QueueName)
```

Or a simpler:

`enter code here`Owner:Queue.QueueName

It's available in reports and dashboard filter.

I don't know why SF do not give this as a builtin feature, but hey, it's only 9 years idea on Ideas site :-)